Dimension Too Large Error Overleaf Euler's Number
I am getting a Dimension Too Large Error at the Section labeled "Solution Curve" and altering and scaling the range and domain isn't helping. What other ways could I approach the Dimension Too Large Error? Thanks.
**Thanks all, it did turns out to be the domain.
\RequirePackage{etex}

\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}

\usepackage{float}


\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{etex}

\usepackage{morewrites}


\allowdisplaybreaks
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent 0ex %remove paragraph indent



\setlength{\jot}{10pt} 


\begin{document}


%========== SLOPE FIELD GRAPH ==============

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7, declare function={f(\x,\y)=(\x)+3*(\y)/(\x);}] %change scale to make the graph larger or smaller; change slope equation

\def\xmax{5} \def\xmin{-5} %change domain of grid

\def\ymax{5} \def\ymin{-5} %change range of grid

\def\nx{10} %change number of horizontal subintervals

\def\ny{10} %change number of vertical subintervals

%\clip (\xmin-1,\ymin-1) rectangle (\xmax+1,\ymax+1);

%============ SLOPE MARKS ================

\pgfmathsetmacro{\hx}{(\xmax-\xmin)/\nx}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\hy}{(\ymax-\ymin)/\ny}

\foreach \i in {0,...,\nx} 

\foreach \j in {0,...,\ny}{
\ifnum\i=5 %Since "i=5" causes a division by zero error, I've excluded it from the list. Change this number to 5000 if this does not apply to your problem.

\else 

\pgfmathsetmacro{\yprime}{f({\xmin+\i*\hx},{\ymin+\j*\hy})}

\draw[blue,thick, shift={({\xmin+\i*\hx},{\ymin+\j*\hy})}] 

(0,0)--($(0,0)!4mm!(.1,.1*\yprime)$);
\fi
} %change 4mm to shorten or lengthen tangent lines

%========== SOLUTION CURVE ===============

\begin{scope}

\clip (\xmin,\ymin-0.5) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);

\draw[red, thick, samples=100] plot[domain=\xmin:\xmax, yrange=\ymin:\ymax] (\x,{-exp(2*\x) + 4*exp(-3*\x)}); %change particular solution equation

\end{scope}

%========== INITIAL CONDITION ==============

\draw[red] (0,3) circle[radius=3pt] node[fill=white, below left] 
{$(0,3)$};  %change coordinates of initial condition, change label

\fill[red] (0,3) circle[radius=3pt]; %change coordinates of initial condition, change radius

\draw[blue] (0.20,5.5339) circle[radius=3pt];  %change coordinates, change radius

\fill[blue] (0.20,5.5339) circle[radius=3pt]; %change coordinates, change radius



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{enumerate}


\end{document}

The Lines of Code specific to the error I am getting:
 %========== SOLUTION CURVE ===============
    
    \begin{scope}
    
    \clip (\xmin,\ymin-0.5) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);
    
    \draw[red, thick, samples=100] plot[domain=\xmin:\xmax, yrange=\ymin:\ymax] (\x,{-exp(2*\x) + 4*exp(-3*\x)}); %change particular solution equation
    
    \end{scope}


It's specifically \draw[red, thick, samples=100] plot[domain=\xmin:\xmax, yrange=\ymin:\ymax] (\x,{-exp(2*\x) + 4exp(-3\x)}); that is resulting in the error. I just don't know how to fix it.

it's not really true that changing the domain makes no difference. if you make it small enough, you avoid the errors. e.g. (-1,3) for each of x and y works. (but increasing the upper limit or decreasing the lower further triggers errors again.)

Hmm, I don't get a "dimension too large" error message when I try to compile your code. Instead, I get a "Runaway argument? Paragraph ended before \pgffor@next was complete" error message at line 56.

The domain of your plot is too big. Instead of doing domain=\xmin:\xmax, I'd use values like -1 and 1. For instance: 4*exp(-3*\x) where \x is -5 is going to be four times e to the power of 15 - which is huge, hence the dimensions too large error.

For this particular function the answer is simply change the domain, however other users might find this question with a different function, for those the stuff at the bottom of this answer might turn out helpful.
As @Jasper noted in his comment your problem is that your domain yields way too big numbers. In particular for -5 your result is 13076069.489843043 which is way too big (the miximum domain that still works is roughly [-1.6565, 3.1779], though that gets cut off anyway since it's way bigger than your specified y-domain, which is already the case for the domain [-1, 1]).

A potential fix for different functions
However not only can your results be too big but also some steps along the way (that's not the case for your specific function, but for other functions this might happen).
Only for the case, that your final result isn't too big but the subterms of the calculation are, you can use the pgfmath-xfp package to fix this issue (it should also yield more precise results for many functions, since it internally uses l3fp which uses a mantissa of 16 decimal figures). Please note that l3fp doesn't support all functions TikZ does out of the box, but see the documentation of pgfmath-xfp for an approach to circumvent that.
Applied to this function an MWE using pgfmath-xfp might look like the following:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfmath-xfp}

\begin{document}
%========== SLOPE FIELD GRAPH ==============
\begin{center}
  % change scale to make the graph larger or smaller
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
    \def\xmax{1} \def\xmin{-1} %change domain of grid
    \def\ymax{5} \def\ymin{-5} %change range of grid
    \def\nx{10} %change number of horizontal subintervals
    \def\ny{10} %change number of vertical subintervals
    %\clip (\xmin-1,\ymin-1) rectangle (\xmax+1,\ymax+1);

    %============ SLOPE MARKS ================
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\hx}{(\xmax-\xmin)/\nx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\hy}{(\ymax-\ymin)/\ny}
    % change slope equation
    \pgfmxfpdeclarefunction{f}{2}{#1+3*(#2)/(#1)}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\nx}
      \foreach \j in {0,...,\ny}{
        % Since "i=5" causes a division by zero error, I've excluded it from the
        % list. Change this number to 5000 if this does not apply to your
        % problem.
        \ifnum\i=5
        \else
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\yprime}{f({\xmin+\i*\hx},{\ymin+\j*\hy})}
          \draw[blue,thick, shift={({\xmin+\i*\hx},{\ymin+\j*\hy})}]
          (0,0)--($(0,0)!4mm!(.1,.1*\yprime)$);
        \fi
      } %change 4mm to shorten or lengthen tangent lines

    %========== SOLUTION CURVE ===============
    \begin{scope}
      \clip (\xmin,\ymin-0.5) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);
      % change particular solution equation
      \pgfmxfpdeclarefunction{sol}{1}{-exp(2*#1) + 4*exp(-3*#1)}
      \draw[red, thick]
        plot[domain=\xmin:\xmax, yrange=\ymin:\ymax, samples=100]
          (\x,{sol(\x)});
    \end{scope}

    %========== INITIAL CONDITION ==============
    % change coordinates of initial condition, change label
    \draw[red] (0,3) circle[radius=3pt] node[fill=white, below left] {$(0,3)$};
    % change coordinates of initial condition, change radius
    \fill[red] (0,3) circle[radius=3pt];
    % change coordinates, change radius
    \draw[blue] (0.20,5.5339) circle[radius=3pt];
    % change coordinates, change radius
    \fill[blue] (0.20,5.5339) circle[radius=3pt];
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}


(deleting my comment)
